# Subtracting the ideal-rank-mean in Wilcoxon rank-sum, what does it do

Tags: mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am reading Discovering Statistics using R by Andy Field. In the section about how to calculate the rank statistic in MWU, one of the steps is to subtract the mean rank from the sum of ranks.

W = sum of ranks − mean rank

The idea being, that it corrects for the number of people in the group.

But what we are subtracting is not the true mean of the summed ranks, but the ideal mean (there are ten observations, and the sum is [1+2+...+10], whereas the actual ranks are 1,2,3.5,....12,  because of ties.

When we usually remove the mean from a sample it is to create a centering. what does this procedure do in this context? I am not a very math-literate person, so some intuitive understanding of what is going on would be helpful

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a further discussion on [Datamethods](https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/does-subtracting-or-not-the-mean-rank-in-wilcoxon-mann-whitney-make-any-difference/7425). The resource I found most useful are [Violation of proportional odds](https://www.fharrell.com/post/po/) and [MWU and Proportional odds](https://www.fharrell.com/post/powilcoxon/).

My current understanding is :

The test reports the probability that a randomly selected value from one list would be larger than a similarly selected one from the second list. This is best reported as concordance probability.

If the samples are of the same size the subtraction is not doing much other than standardizing reporting and helps in calculating the concordance probability which is $U1 / (n1 * n2)$

When the samples are of different sizes, it controls for the advantage that the larger sample will have, because sum of ranks depends on number of samples.

Answer (score 2):

*This is my first answer on CV, so please make edits or let me know if it is wrong or missing anything!*

Now onto your question.

### Why not just the rank-sum?

First the conclusion: comparing the rank-sum itself across different datasets is not meaningful. Subtracting that "mean rank" makes comparison (somewhat more) meaningful.

Without subtracting, the rank-sum itself is not comparable across different datasets:

> For example, if we have two datasets, with two groups (call them $A$ and $B$) separated by a bar: the first being $(3,4|1,2)$, and the second being $(1,2,3,4|5,6,7,8)$.
>
> Then in the first dataset, observations from $A$ are the largest of the dataset, and the rank-sum of $A$ is $3+4=7$.
>
> In the second, $A$ has a higher rank-sum of $1+2+3+4=10$ despite being the lowest observations, simply because the dataset is larger.
>
> This means that we cannot directly look at a rank-sum of (say) $10$ and decide whether it is large without knowing the size of the dataset.

However, if we subtract the "mean rank" of the rank-sum to get the MVU, comparing the MVU across datasets make more sense:

> The first dataset has a MWU of $7 - 2(2+1)/2=4$, and the second dataset has a smaller MVU of $10 - 4(4+1)/2 = 0$. This matches the intuition better.
>
> In general, rank-sums from a larger dataset will be subtracted by a larger "mean rank", and the results are more comparable across datasets of different sizes.

---

### What does the MWU mean?

Again, the conclusion first: the MVU answers the question *"how much is the rank-sum higher than its smallest value possible?"*. In other words, instead of centering anything, subtracting the "mean rank" creates a **meaningful zero** of the MWU.

I've been using mean rank in quotation marks, because IMHO the name "mean rank" is quite misleading, as it is not the mean of anything meaningful. Instead, it is the *minimal possible value* of the rank-sums (when there are no ties).

> Suppose the group $A$ has $N$ people $(a_1, \dots, a_N)$, and $B$ has $M$ people $(b_1,\dots, b_M)$, and we are computing the ranks of people in group $A$. In the most extreme case, everyone in $A$ has a lower value than everyone in $B$, so the groups sorted by their numbers will look like $$a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_N},b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_M}.$$Now group $A$ gets ranks $1,\dots N$ and group $B$ gets $N+1,\dots,M+N$, and the rank-sum of group $A$ is $N(N+1)/2$, i.e. the "mean rank" the book talks about.

In conclusion, for a group of size $N$ (in a larger dataset), the number $1+2+\cdots+N=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ is the smallest rank-sum it can have.

---

#### Does this really matter?

IMHO, no (unless of course you are comparing rank-sums across different datasets). In fact, my university course uses the original rank-sum (without subtracting the "mean rank") and calls it the "**Wilcoxon rank sum statistic**". Hypothesis testing with that is identical to using the MWU.

To be precise, if you use the MWU/rank-sum to find p-values for hypothesis testing, *subtracting this constant value (or not) does not affect the test's conclusion*. It only shifts the entire distribution around (analogous to how changing $\mu$ in the Gaussian distribution $N(\mu,1)$ shifts it around), and the p-values is not affected.

Comment: Thank you! So, the subtraction is being done for the ease of comparison, that is it? one would come to the same conclusions anyway? The idea that it is not a mean but that it is the lowest possible value is illuminating!

Comment: To adjust for the size of the dataset, doesnt it make sense to divide by the N. that way the first dataset would have a rank of 3.5 and the second would have a rank of 2.5

Comment: @aflip To be honest I'm not sure why the subtraction is done, or if it is done on purpose at all. An equivalent definition of the MWU is $\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\mathbf{1}\{a_{i} > b_{j}\}$, i.e. the number of $(a_i,b_j)$ pairs where the $a_i$ is larger than the $b_j$. It just turns out to equal the rank-sum definition, and there is no subtraction going on. Maybe scaling/centering was not the top priority when Wilcoxon, Mann, and Whitney came up with those statistics.

Comment: Dividing by $N$ is a nice idea, but in fact the rank-sum grows quadratically when the dataset grows: if the size of the dataset is $K$, and the group is half of the dataset (so $N=K/2$), then both the number of observations and their ranks grow proportional to $K$.

Comment: @aflip In fact it's not uncommon to compute $p=\frac{U}{n_1 n_2}$, the proportion of times that a sample A value exceeds a B value) which under random sampling of the populations is a suitable estimate of the corresponding population parameter, the probability that a randomly selected A exceeds a randomly selected B